# Nginx reverse proxy allow traffic based on cookie presence

Tags: cookies, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a small Linux server acting as a reverse proxy running Nginx.  The main server behind Nginx is running a website in asp.net with a forms authentication login and an instance of ArcServer, running some REST services on port 6080.

Is it possible to only allow traffic to port 6080 on Nginx to people that have a session cookie from the asp.net login?  Basically I only want logged in users to be able to access those REST services and not the whole wide web.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I am running short on ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear on one server at port 80 you set a cookie when user log in and when user is trying to connect to port 6080 on that server you would like to pass only users with that cookie, yes?

Answer (score 1):

The following works quite well. But naturally is only a bit of obfuscation and doesn't replace  any security checking deeper in the app

```
location /url/to/secret/ {
   if ($cookie_secretCookieName) {
     proxy_pass  http://serverhere;
   }    
}
```

This wouldn't prevent anyone that knows the cookie name from getting access e.g. someone who was a user and isn't anymore; but it could be a nice extra step to reduce a bit of load on your servers